# Enable the QuickLaunch Fly Out Menu in subsite only

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, site-collection, sub-site, design-manager

I am using Sharepoint 2013 and I want to apply the QuickLaunch Fly Out in one subsite only.
I followed the post [The Right Way to Enable the QuickLaunch Fly Out Menu in SharePoint 2013](https://www.advisicon.com/2013/12/03/right-way-enable-quicklaunch-fly-menu-sharepoint-2013/)

It worked, but the fly out menu is applied to all site collection and all subsites. Is it possible to apply it in one subsite only? If not is there any workaround to this?

Because I have many subsites under the same site collection each has its different requirement and functions.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your attached article it's a normal behavior for your changes to be applied for all site collection and all subsites.

This is Because of you have changed the master page of your site collection then apply this for all subsite as the author mentioned in his article.

[image]

**To let it work for a specific subsite you should do the following :**

- Try to copy `Seattle master page` (HTML file), rename it.

[image]

- Apply your menu fly changes for this custom master page based on the instructions mentioned at [The Right Way to Enable the QuickLaunch Fly Out Menu in SharePoint 2013](https://www.advisicon.com/2013/12/03/right-way-enable-quicklaunch-fly-menu-sharepoint-2013/)
- Now you will need to assign this master page only for this subsite by doing the following :

  - Go to your subsite > site setting > below look and feel > Master Page > and select `Specify a master page to be used by this site and all sites that inherit from it:` > select your custom master page .

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I've been trying to do this. but every time I click on the Master Page in my subsite it directs me back to the top level site.
how can I break this inheritance?

Comment: back to the top level site ?! How this ? should you elaborate more ? are you activate the SharePoint Server Publishing feature at manage site features below your site

Comment: Thanx for your help. It turned out that the feature "SharePoint Server Publishing" was activated on the top level only. after activating it on the subsite I could apply the changes on that subsite only.